# JQuery Keyboard events & Regex logic

Tags: jquery

I have TextBox in which user can type only Alphabets(Lower&Upper), Hyphen (-), BackSpace only. These will be basically any Qualified URL name page like Contact/my-contact etc

**I need Regex and restriction of keyboard keys on that Textbox**.

For keyboard logic below code is not working properly as well so need help

```
jQuery('#UrlName').keypress(function (e) {
    code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if ((code.toString() > 45 || code.toString() < 57) && (code.toString() < 97 || code.toString() > 122)) return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
jQuery('#UrlName').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 8) return true;
    if (!/[A-Z\-]/i.test(String.fromCharCode(e.which))) return false;           
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/77feF/

Comment: Thanks . There is one problem I can not use Backspace to delete what I have typed. Can you fix that Please

Comment: @ pirzada `if (e.which == 8) return true;` added to my answer